# Divide sections in progress bar

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-5

I am working on angular app and I am very new to html and css. I am trying to make a progress bar. I want to divide each section of this progress bar into two sub sections with different background color as shown here in the image below.
[image: progress_bar]

my code is as follows:

```css
    .wrap {
      width: 100%;
      height: 30px;
      z-index: -2;
      white-space: nowrap;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .wrap div:first-child {
      margin-left: -2%;
    }
    
    .progress {
      margin: 0;
      margin-left: 0.5%;
      height: 30px;
      width: 25%;
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 30px;
      transition: all 0.8s;
    }
    
    .progress:before,
    .progress:after {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      transition: all 0.8s;
      z-index: -1;
    }
    
    .progress:before {
      height: 50%;
      width: 100%;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      transform: skew(45deg);
    }
    
    .progress:after {
      height: 50%;
      width: 100%;
      top: 50%;
      left: 0;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      transform: skew(-45deg);
    }
    
    .progress:hover:before,
    .progress:hover:after {
      background: tomato;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="progress">
        simple
      </div>
      <div class="progress">
        as
      </div>
      <div class="progress">
        complex
      </div>
      <div class="progress">
        Web Development
      </div>
    </div>
```

How can I do this? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  z-index: -2;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrap div:first-child {
  margin-left: -2%;
}

.progress {
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 0.5%;
  height: 30px;
  width: 25%;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  transition: all 0.8s;
}

.progress:before,
.progress:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.8s;
  z-index: -1;
}

.progress:before {
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transform: skew(45deg);
}

.progress:after {
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transform: skew(-45deg);
}
#div1{
width:60%;

}
#div2{
width:40%;

}

#div2:hover:before,#div2:hover:after
{
  background: green !important;
}
#div1:hover:before,#div1:hover:after
{
  background: orange; !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
                      <div class="progress">
              <div class="progress" id="div1">simple</div>
              <div class="progress" id="div2">simple</div>
            </div>
                      <div class="progress">
                        as
                      </div>
                      <div class="progress">
                        complex
                      </div>
                      <div class="progress">
                        Web Development
                      </div>
                </div>
```

```
   .wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  z-index: -2;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrap div:first-child {
  margin-left: -2%;
}

.progress {
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 0.5%;
  height: 30px;
  width: 25%;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  transition: all 0.8s;
}

.progress:before,
.progress:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.8s;
  z-index: -1;
}

.progress:before {
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transform: skew(45deg);
}

.progress:after {
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transform: skew(-45deg);
}
#div1{
width:60%;

}
#div2{
width:40%;

}

#div2:hover:before,#div2:hover:after
{
  background: green !important;
}
#div1:hover:before,#div1:hover:after
{
  background: orange; !important;
}
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress" id="div1">simple</div>
        <div class="progress" id="div2">simple</div>
      </div>
      <div class="progress">
        as
      </div>
      <div class="progress">
        complex
      </div>
      <div class="progress">
        Web Development
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: can you make your code run? in stackblitz or here in stackoverflow

Comment: yes u can run it now

Comment: this yellow color of second simple is not in line with the backone. that's why tip is extra visible

Comment: Actually I tried to solve your question regarding to divs for appearance you can manage it with help of css

Comment: I just edit the code can u please re-check it

Answer (score 0):

You could use a linear gradient, e.g.:

```
background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0,212,255,1) 80%, rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 80%);
```

```css
    .wrap {
      width: 100%;
      height: 30px;
      z-index: -2;
      white-space: nowrap;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .wrap div:first-child {
      margin-left: -2%;
    }
    
    .progress {
      margin: 0;
      margin-left: 0.5%;
      height: 30px;
      width: 25%;
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 30px;
      transition: all 0.8s;
    }
    
    .progress:before,
    .progress:after {
      content: "";
      background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0,212,255,1) 80%, rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 80%);
      position: absolute;
      transition: all 0.8s;
      z-index: -1;
    }
    
    .progress:before {
      height: 50%;
      width: 100%;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      transform: skew(45deg);
    }
    
    .progress:after {
      height: 50%;
      width: 100%;
      top: 50%;
      left: 0;
      transform: skew(-45deg);
    }
    
    .progress:hover:before,
    .progress:hover:after {
      background: tomato;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="progress">
        simple
      </div>
      <div class="progress">
<div style="display:inline-block;width:80%;">80%</div>
<div style="display:inline-block;width:20%;">20%</div>
      </div>
      <div class="progress">
        complex
      </div>
      <div class="progress">
        Web Development
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi, this blue color inside is shown with title borders- right side border.  can we have it as straight line. and if progress reaches to the end it is in align with arrow?